# Is there any way to install a browser extension using Airwatch?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, vmware, airwatch

I'd like to deploy/install a Firefox add-on or Google chrome extension using the VMware workspace one UEM (formerly known as Airwatch) on Windows 10 platform.

Is there any way to perform these browser based extensions in Airwatch?

Answer (score 0):

it took around more than a month but some guys at our organization were able to figure out how to deploy extension via Airwatch here is how you can do it:
Go to
Airwatch -> Devices -> Profile -> Add
Create a profile according to OS then go to custom settings, click configure. It will allow you to paste you xml to apply and revert changes in the respective boxes.
What you are going to de here is play with the window's registry :

1. Create a folder named ExtensionInstallForcelist at this pathHKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\
2. update the name of key to any integer like '12'
3. update the key value to extensionId;path to your extension(cxr)
   if your id 1234 and path to extension is https://clients2.google.com/service2/update14/crx
   then key value should be 1234;https://clients2.google.com/service2/update14/crx
   That's it if the folder is created your extension will be installed automatically.

Comment: Here is example for XML:
Install setting:

<wap-provisioningdoc id="1164DF07-F217-449B-95F8-FB85A34D3CA7" name="customprofile">/
    <characteristic type="com.airwatch.winrt.registryoperation" uuid="4fa91319-eac0-4a16-9d10-093ba845b692">
----------------Only change this part below
        <parm RegistryPath="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist" Action="Replace">
            <Value Name="12" Data="1234;https://clients2.google.com/service/update14/crx" Type="String" />
        </parm>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add all of the infomation there. It's very hard to read as a comment.